# Need some assistance with SQL Self-join logic ( via SQLZoo )?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm studying self-joins ,and on this question :

```
SELECT a.company, a.num, stopa.name, stopb.name
FROM route a JOIN route b ON
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
  JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
  JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
WHERE stopa.name='Craiglockhart'
    AND  stopb.name='London Road'
```

which [is #6 on this website](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join) ,

I'm not seeing why we use the clause :

```
  (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
```

If we are checking for two different stops - 'Craiglockhart' and 'London Road' , then why are we using `a.company = b.company` AND `a.num = b.num`

I.E why is it not simply:

```
a.stop = b.stop
```

NOTE: As I was asking the question, the answer came to me . So I decided to finish and post an answer, for self-reference

Comment: NOTE: I figured this out, but wanted to answer it anyway for self-study purpose

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because when we `SELF-JOIN`  , we need to carefully view the structure of the table we are joining on .

iE in this example, the `num` and `company` columns will stay constant, however the `stop` column changes.

i.e if we joined using hte  clause `r1.stop = r2.stop` , then that would not make any sense because we are stuck on *one* stop

Answer (score 0):

Why u use self join we dont know.Self join mainly used for parent-child relationship table.
For U r Case easily U get the data by

```
    SELECT a.company, a.num, stopa.name
    FROM route a 
    JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id) 
    WHERE stopa.name='Craiglockhart'
          OR  stopa.name='London Road'
```